# Image Filter in Swift

Tags: ios

can we make the image filter in swift using "irtemplate file" received from adobe Lightroom preset? 
Detail Description --- I have used adobe Lightroom preset for filtering the image and create the file of .irtemplate of changed values of like contrast, brightness etc, and using this files value I want make the filter a image in swift, is it possible?.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is .lrtemplate and not .irtemplate (lr as in LightRoom).

The values in an .lrtemplate file are parameters used by Adobes image engine and are proprietary for Lightroom and thus not something Apples image engine understand so you would need to have a converter between the two and I doubt that is an easy task.

Another option is to research if Adobe has some API so you could use the Lightroom iOS version to process your images and if that API uses the same parameters found in the templates.

Lastly, note that Adobe has moved to a new file format for presets, .XMP, that is interchangeable between Lightroom, Photoshop and CameraRaw.